# How can I get the list of all tracking markers using python command

Tags: python, tracking, movie-clip-editor

I want to get the list of all tracking markers for the active clip in the clip editor and loop through each marker, so that I can do something with the markers, like get the (x,y) co-ordinate or delete it or change any other values like weight of the marker using python

Answer (score 1):

This script

```py
import bpy
D = bpy.data

for clip in D.movieclips:
    for track in clip.tracking.tracks:
        fn = 'data/tr_{0}_{1}.csv'.format(clip.name.split('.')[0], track.name)
        with open(fn, 'w') as f:
            frameno = 0
            while True:
                markerAtFrame = track.markers.find_frame(frameno)
                if not markerAtFrame:
                    break
                frameno += 1
                coords = markerAtFrame.co.xy
                f.write('{0} {1}n'.format(coords[0], coords[1]))
```

from [Blender: exporting camera tracking markers to CSV](http://blog.svenbrauch.de/2012/11/25/blender-exporting-camera-tracking/) contains code to do what you're looking for.  You'll have to adapt it, of course.